# window phone - method is not run ?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I create a method in class :

```
public async void Foo()
 {
           .....
          string response = await Utilities.sendData(data);
          ....

}
```

I create break point and run,when it call foo method,but break point run at

```
string response = await Utilities.sendData(data)
```

and then break point is disappear,if i call in code behind (xaml)it no problem

Answer (score 0):

You can call an async method from synchronous code.

The async modifier says that the code within that method can await on other async methods. Here's a silly example

```
public class Foo
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        await Something(); //invalid
        Something(); //valid
    }

    public async void Something() 
    {
        await SomethingElse(); //valid
        SomethingElse(); // also valid, but synchronous
    }

    public async void SomethingElse()
    {
    }
}
```